# how to deploy notebook into player pro

Tags: cdf-format, deployment

I want to ask how can I deploy`Mathematica` notebook into player pro. I know that online conversion to `Mathematica player pro` is there. But is there any function for player pro as there is `CDFDeploy` for deploying notebook in CDF?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think deployment to CDF is intended to replace the old online conversion.  I think that someone using Player Pro will have the additional permissions on your deployed CDF.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, it has some additional permissions but I dont know how to deploy notebok to player pro.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK there is nothing you need to do to deploy to Player Pro: you can just give away the notebook as it is. A user with Player Pro can then just shift-return-evaluate the input cells to run the code. The ony thing that can't be done within Player Pro is to edit the notebook, so you have to provide gui-elements for the input the user need to enter...

As Mr. Wizard has mentioned, you could just as well deploy to CDF. When a CDF is opened with Player Pro the restrictions that exist when opening it with CDF-Player will be lifted, so that you can e.g. import from local files, export to all supported formats and load (`Encode`d) packages. Deploying the following to a CDF-document will generate error messages (`OpenRead::sandbox`) when run in the CDF-player but work alright in Player Pro:

```
Button["import",
 Module[{filename = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]},
  Print[filename];
  Print[Import[filename]];
  ], Method -> "Queued"]
```